# Finding the size of Hexadecimal char array in C from PROGMEM

Tags: c, hex, microcontroller, avr, progmem

I'm working on a AT90 micro controller and I'm working on displaying different fonts on the screen. As part of my font definition, I've got a char array of hexadecimal below. For the purpose of this question, I've shorten the char array to only represent 4 characters.

```
const char font5x7[] PROGMEM = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // SPACE
    0x00, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x00, // !
    0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, // "
    0x14, 0x3E, 0x14, 0x3E, 0x14  // #
}
```

Now if I run `sizeof(font5x7)`, it gives me the correct answer which is 20. However when I run my real `font5x7`, it returns `475` instead of the correct number `225`. Here is the real one:

```
const char font5x7[] PROGMEM = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // SPACE
    0x00, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x00, // !
    0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, // "
    0x14, 0x3E, 0x14, 0x3E, 0x14, // #
    0x24, 0x2A, 0x7F, 0x2A, 0x12, // $
    0x43, 0x33, 0x08, 0x66, 0x61, // %
    0x36, 0x49, 0x55, 0x22, 0x50, // &
    0x00, 0x05, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, // '
    0x00, 0x1C, 0x22, 0x41, 0x00, // (
    0x00, 0x41, 0x22, 0x1C, 0x00, // )
    0x14, 0x08, 0x3E, 0x08, 0x14, // *
    0x08, 0x08, 0x3E, 0x08, 0x08, // +
    0x00, 0x50, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, // ,
    0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, // -
    0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, // .
    0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, // /
    0x3E, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x3E, // 0
    0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x00, // 1
    0x42, 0x61, 0x51, 0x49, 0x46, // 2
    0x22, 0x41, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, // 3
    0x18, 0x14, 0x12, 0x7F, 0x10, // 4
    0x27, 0x45, 0x45, 0x45, 0x39, // 5
    0x3E, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x32, // 6
    0x01, 0x01, 0x71, 0x09, 0x07, // 7
    0x36, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, // 8
    0x26, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x3E, // 9
    0x00, 0x36, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, // :
    0x00, 0x56, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, // ;
    0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x41, 0x00, // <
    0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, // =
    0x00, 0x41, 0x22, 0x14, 0x08, // >
    0x02, 0x01, 0x51, 0x09, 0x06, // ?
    0x3E, 0x41, 0x59, 0x55, 0x5E, // @
    0x7E, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x7E, // A
    0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, // B
    0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22, // C
    0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E, // D
    0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x41, // E
    0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x01, // F
    0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x49, 0x3A, // G
    0x7F, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x7F, // H
    0x00, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x00, // I
    0x30, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x3F, // J
    0x7F, 0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x41, // K
    0x7F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, // L
    0x7F, 0x02, 0x0C, 0x02, 0x7F, // M
    0x7F, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x7F, // N
    0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E, // O
    0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06, // P
    0x1E, 0x21, 0x21, 0x21, 0x5E, // Q
    0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x76, // R
    0x26, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x32, // S
    0x01, 0x01, 0x7F, 0x01, 0x01, // T
    0x3F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x3F, // U
    0x1F, 0x20, 0x40, 0x20, 0x1F, // V
    0x7F, 0x20, 0x10, 0x20, 0x7F, // W
    0x41, 0x22, 0x1C, 0x22, 0x41, // X
    0x07, 0x08, 0x70, 0x08, 0x07, // Y
    0x61, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x43, // Z
    0x00, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, // [
    0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, // slash 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x00, // ]
    0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, // ^
    0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, // _
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00, // `
    0x20, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x78, // a
    0x7F, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38, // b
    0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, // c
    0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x7F, // d
    0x38, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x18, // e
    0x04, 0x04, 0x7E, 0x05, 0x05, // f
    0x08, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x3C, // g
    0x7F, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78, // h
    0x00, 0x44, 0x7D, 0x40, 0x00, // i
    0x20, 0x40, 0x44, 0x3D, 0x00, // j
    0x7F, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44, 0x00, // k
    0x00, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x40, 0x00, // l
    0x7C, 0x04, 0x78, 0x04, 0x78, // m
    0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78, // n
    0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38, // o
    0x7C, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x08, // p
    0x08, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x7C, // q
    0x00, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, // r
    0x48, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x20, // s
    0x04, 0x04, 0x3F, 0x44, 0x44, // t
    0x3C, 0x40, 0x40, 0x20, 0x7C, // u
    0x1C, 0x20, 0x40, 0x20, 0x1C, // v
    0x3C, 0x40, 0x30, 0x40, 0x3C, // w
    0x44, 0x28, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44, // x
    0x0C, 0x50, 0x50, 0x50, 0x3C, // y
    0x44, 0x64, 0x54, 0x4C, 0x44, // z
    0x00, 0x08, 0x36, 0x41, 0x41, // {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00, // |
    0x41, 0x41, 0x36, 0x08, 0x00, // }
    0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x02};// ~
```

Comment: `sizeof(font5x7)` should work.

Comment: what is returned by `sizeof(font5x7)`?

Comment: What is `PROGMEN`?  Suspect that is a compiler specific keyword that is messing up `sizeof()`.  If you drop it, do you get 20?

Comment: @chux PROGMEN allows me to place this array in the program memory(flash) so that it doesn't take up any of my RAM. I've tried it without PROGMEN but the same behaviour occurs.

Comment: @Lashane I'm unsure what the value of sizeof(font5x7) is. When I cross-compile it onto my AVR, I don't have any printf feature which is making my life very difficult. But I suspect it returns a large value, possibly the size of array in bytes!?

Comment: @Ivan hm, length of char array usually equals to size of this array in bytes

Comment: @Ivan the size of this array in bytes is `20` and you say that you want `20` as the result

Comment: @ivan "I'm unsure what the value of sizeof(font5x7) is". So how are you concluding that "it didn't give me anything helpful"? Are you saying you don't know what `sizeof(font5x7)` gives but you somehow know it is wrong?

Comment: To test values at compile-time you can write code that would be invalid for certain values, e.g. `typedef char x[ sizeof(font5x7) == 20 ? 1 : -1 ];`  which will give a compile error only if the size is not 20, because there cannot be a typedef for an array of negative dimension

Comment: @kaylum I've the display of my font by hardcoding (20 in this case) in my code and it works perfectly. So I'm also wondering if there is accessing from PROGMEM would have any affect to the function `sizeof()`

Comment: @M.M This will come in handy, thank you!

Comment: "I've tried to use the following but it didn't give me anything helpful." --> is not that helpful.  What does `sizeof(font5x7)` give?

Comment: @chux You guys were absolutely right, I was able to implement my own print function on my AVR and can confirm that it does output `20`. However when I'm working with my real file, it seems to output the wrong value :/ 
I've updated my question above

Comment: I don't see the problem. You have 95 lines, each containing 5 bytes. And **5 x 95 = 475**.

Comment: @RadLexus Ah.. I must be confused at one point. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Side note:: Suspect code will benefit by using `unsigned char` than `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code prints "Array len: 20" on my system.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PROGMEM

const char font5x7[] PROGMEM = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // SPACE
    0x00, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x00, // !
    0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, // "
    0x14, 0x3E, 0x14, 0x3E, 0x14  // #
};

#define ARRAY_LEN(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

const font5x7_len = ARRAY_LEN(font5x7);
int main(void) {
    printf("Array len: %d\n", font5x7_len);
}
```

Comment: This is a comment (albeit a detailed one), but it doesn't help to answer the question.

Comment: The question was *"How can I count the number of hexadecimals represented in this array so that it will equate to 20?"* This seems like a pretty good answer to that question, IMO.

Comment: @AustinHastings You guys were absolutely right, I was able to implement my own print function on my AVR and can confirm that it does output 20. However when I'm working with my real file, it seems to output the wrong value :/ I've updated my question above

Comment: As another commenter mentioned, 475 is the right value. But IIRC, you were trying to determine the character width within the font, or something. Can you elaborate on that, or do you already have it?

Answer (score -1):

In C programming, arrays are little more than pointers. While you are still in the scope where you declared the array you can use sizeof(font5x7) / sizeof(char) to determine the length of the array.

However, when an array is passed into a function, it decays into a pointer. Pointers have no associated length so you need to keep another variable describing how long the array.

In other words, the function you want is impossible without some kind of sentinel value. For instance if you could guarantee that your font array will never contain a `0xff`, then you could end every array with `0xff`. Your function would then search through the array until it finds that value and return the length.